# Four tables query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, one-to-many

i would like get all data from four table by one query. My tables

Categories

```
id

name
```

Subcategories

```
id

name
```

categories_subcategories

```
id

category_id

subcategory_id
```

items

```
id

name

category_subcategory_id
```

one product can be in one category and subcategory, i have query between category and subcategory and would like add to this item table.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
    ];

    protected $table = 'subcategories';


    public function categoriesTwoLevel()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CategoriesTwoLevel::class, 'categories_subcategories', 'subcategories_id','categories_id');
    }
}


class Categories extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
    ];

    protected $table = 'categories_two_level';

    protected $timestamp = false;

    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subcategory::class, 'categories_subcategories', 'categories_id', 'subcategories_id')->withPivot('id');
    }

}
```

this is query which get all data from Subcategory and Category tables by table categories_subcategories

```
CategoriesTwoLevel::with('subcategory')->get();
```

but tables items has not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dot notation to load nested relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) data:

```
Categories::with('subcategory.categoriesTwoLevel.items')->get();
```

This will work if you correctly defined all these relationships.

Comment: Ok, but I'm have a little problem. Like I should have made relation in Categories model to item table?

Comment: @Piffek no, you need to define relationship between `CategoriesTwoLevel` and `Item`

Comment: Ok, but CategoriesTwoLevel and Item has not relationship, relationship is between  Item and CategoriesTwoLevel_subcategory (this is table with relations to Subcategory and CategoriesTwoLevel relation)       
   CategoriesTwoLevel id name

Subcategories id name

categories_subcategories id categoriesTwoLevel_id subcategory_id

items id name category_subcategory_id

Comment: @Piffek I'd recommend you to refactor your models because now these are kind of messy. I think you got the idea of nested eager loading, so just use real existing relationships to load items.

Comment: This is good idea. I would like refactoring this, but i don't know what. You have any idea?